# Is there any way to draw curved lines or rectangles in Andengine?

Tags: andengine, curve

I have to draw curved Lines or rectangles in Andengine. Please tell me the way if anyone know.

Comment: There is rectangle class in andengine in primitives package, so no problem here. Curves are tricky though. What kind of curves do you have in mind? Bezier?

Comment: Yes Bezier Curves... But rectangle class will only draw straight lines.

Comment: Oh... I just got what you have in mind... A curved rectangle.... Well it is also possible. Similarly to the LineStrip I shown you in the answer, you use Mesh class to make a rectangle made of many triangles - a triangle strip. then by changing the coordinates of vertices of trianlges based on bezier calculation you can make edges of rectangle curved. Tricky but doable.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so Rectangle class draws Rectangles, Line class draws lines.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(float pX, float pY, float pWidth, float pHeight, VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager)
```

You set position, width and height here. Put vertex buffer object manager there too, and you're good to go.

Bezier curves are harder to do, since there is no Curve class nor BezierCurve. What I use is LineStrip class:

```
    final VertexBufferObjectManager vbom = engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
    final HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject pLeftCurbLineChainVBOM = new HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject(vbom, triangleCount * 3, DrawType.DYNAMIC, true, leftCurb.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);

LineStrip leftCurb = new LineStrip(0, 0, 2f, 300, pLeftCurbLineChainVBOM){


        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            drawByBezier(curveOffset);

        };

        void drawByBezier(float curveOffset){



            for (int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < 300; triangleIndex++) {

                this.setX(triangleIndex, getBezier(triangleIndex, curveXP1, curveXControl, curveXP2));
                this.setY(triangleIndex, getBezier(triangleIndex, curveYP1, curveYControl, curveYP2));
             }
        }
```

You calculate curve like this:

```
public float getBezier(float triangleIndex, float P1X, float PcX, float P2X){

            float t = triangleIndex / 300;
            float tt = t * t;
            float u = 1 - t;
            float uu = u * u;

            float bezier = (uu * P1X) + (2 * u * t * PcX) + (tt * P2X);

            return bezier;

        }
```

Of course you do not have to do that in onManagedUpdate - it is just from my code, since I modify curve there. Also number 300 as parameter for LineStrip and in the getBezier method doesnt have to be 300, it may be lower or higher, but it must be same in both places. So if you want to have a bezier curve from (100, 100) to (400, 300) with control point at (200, 350) you do that like:

```
    this.setX(triangleIndex, getBezier(triangleIndex, 100, 200, 400));
    this.setY(triangleIndex, getBezier(triangleIndex, 100, 350, 300));
```

Hope it works for you too.